# Is it possible to directly access an amazon workspace volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces

I think Workspaces uses EBS, but the volume itself is not listed under Volumes unlike EC2 instances. Are workspaces volumes managed by AWS itself?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: it is possible to access it, like for example for this use case https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/workspaces-change-volume-size/